# action decorator in DRF doesn't work with url_path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to achive that such endpoint `/api/messages/<str:email>/` will return a list of messages for given email.
So in my ViewSet I've created a function with `@action` decorator

```
@action(
    detail=False,
    methods=["get"],
    name="Get email messages",
    url_path="<str:email>",
    url_name="Email's messages"
)
def email_messages(self, request, email=None):
    return Response({"aaa": email}, status=200)
```

But it seems that django doesn't resolve eg. this url: `/api/messages/aaa/` (just for the test) and returns 404.

Even if I change `url_path` to `email` it returns 404 on `/api/messages/email/`. It only works when I remove the `url_path` kwarg from the params. Then it is accessible under `/api/messages/email_messages`.

How can I achieve a working `GET` on `/api/messages/<str:email/` so that the email will be passed to the function?

Answer (score 20):

It seems DRF does not accept ***Django path expression*** but, the ***regex expression***. So, you need to use **`url_path=r'(?P<email>\w+)'`** instead of `url_path=<str:email>`

Also, this path will overwrite the ***default detail view***, that is, `/api/messages/<PK>/` API. So, I would recommend using some prefix to this email end-point

```
@action(
    detail=False,
    methods=["get"],
    name="Get email messages",
    url_path=r'some-prefix/(?P<email>\w+)',
    url_name="Email's messages"
)
def email_messages(self, request, email=None):
    return Response({"aaa": email}, status=200)
```

now, your API end-point will be, `/api/messages/some-prefix/foo-bar/`