# how to pass extra parameter to django rest custom action inside the viewset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token, custom-action, django-rest-viewsets

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='password-reset/<uid64>/<token>', url_name='password-reset-confirm')
    def password_reset(self, request, uid64, token):
        pass
```

this is the url ( http://localhost:8000/user/2/password-reset/Mg/az44bk-48c221372ceaca98b4090a421131d5f3 ) I am trying to reach, but it keeps returning 404 page not found

Update::

urls file:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from .views import UserViewset, CompanyViewset, ProfileViewset
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', UserViewset, basename='user')
router.register('company', CompanyViewset, basename='company')
router.register('profile', ProfileViewset, basename='profile')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('<int:id>', include(router.urls)),
]
```

views file:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], url_path='request-reset-email', url_name='request-reset-email')
    def request_reset_password_email(self, request, pk):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        email = serializer.data.get('email')
        user = self.get_object()
        if email == user.email:
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
            current_site = get_current_site(request=request).domain
            relativeLink = '/user/' + str(user.id) + '/password-reset/' + token
            absurl = 'http://'+current_site + relativeLink
            email_body = 'Hello \n Use link below to reset your password \n' + absurl
            subject = 'Reset your password'
            send_mail(subject, email_body, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [
                      user.email], fail_silently=False)

            return Response({'success': 'we have sent you an email'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'failed': 'email does not match'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)



@action(detail=True, methods=['patch'], url_path=r'password-reset/(?P<token>\w+)', url_name='password-reset-confirm')
    def set_new_password(self, request, pk, token):
        user = self.get_object()
        if not PasswordResetTokenGenerator().check_token(user, 'az569s-6ad4e11c2f56aa496128bc1c923486cb'):
            return Response({'error': 'Token is not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        password = serializer.data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return Response({'success': 'success'})
```

serializers

```
    class ResetPasswordEmailRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        email = serializers.EmailField()

    class SetNewPasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=20)
```

Recently I have removed the uid64 since I am not using it, tested everything and it does work when hardcode the token in the url

Comment: Can you try with `url_path='password-reset/<str:uid64>/<str:token>'`

Comment: @BrianDestura I did, still not working

Comment: Oh just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089896/action-decorator-in-drf-doesnt-work-with-url-path), apparently you can only use regex expressions. Try and see if that works

Comment: @BrianDestura I've tried this `url_path=r'password-reset/(?P<uid64>\w+)/(?P<token>\w+)'`. I dont know if its written correctly but its not working

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```py
    @action(
        detail=True, 
        methods=['get'], 
        url_path=r'password-reset/(?P<uid64>\w+)/(?P<token>\w+)', 
        url_name='password-reset-confirm'
    )
    def password_reset(self, request, pk, uid64, token):
        pass
```

You will have to capture the three parameters: `pk`, `uid64`, and `token`

Comment: Hi again, I have tried this and it is still not working, even tho everything works perfectly fine when I hardcode the token and uid64 like this `url_path='password-reset/Mg/az45wt-605ef65dedd38ed4561dbe17b1582db9'`

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code you have? I tried this out locally and it works fine

Comment: I did, thanks in advance for trying to help <3

Comment: Ok can you also show what `password_reset` looks like right now? Or is that `set_new_password`?

Comment: oh yeah sorry forgot to mention that too, yes `password_reset` is `set_net_password` now

Comment: And are you hitting the url through a browser? If yes, then the reason why its 404 is because the method is now set to `PATCH` while the browser is doing a `GET`.

Comment: even with `GET`, I still get 404

Comment: Did you mean you used `methods=['get']`?

Comment: yes `methods=['get']` returns 404

Comment: Finally I found the problem, for some reason `(?P<token>\w+)` was not picking up the dash in the token in the URL so it had to be `(?P<token>[-\w]+)`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yeah nice that's great!

Comment: For me, the problem was the URL placeholder; It was like `<token>` as in `urlpatterns`, but it should be in the form of `(?P<token>\w+)`. Still, I don't understand what is it for, however.